# How can I fix the 'saveas' code to save pdf-files containing simulink simulation results by using 'strcat'?

Tags: matlab, save, simulation, simulink, strcat

I am struggled with the following code. I don't understand why the 'saveas' function doesn't work although I gave proper file name, file type and the figure of graphical simulation results of a Simulink model. Do I need to change something in 'strcat' code or? Also I hope that someone helps me in this issue.

```
function nightly_simulation_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
open_system('SimulinkModel.slx');
sim('SimulinkModel.slx');
hFig = findall(0,'tag','SIMULINK_SIMSCOPE_FIGURE');
name = strcat('NCSSimResults','_',num2str(1));
saveas(hFig, name, 'pdf');
```

Resulted errors:

- > Error using checkArgsForHandleToPrint Handle input must be scalar, > vector, or cell array of vectors. 
  >   Error in checkArgsForHandleToPrint > 
  >   Error in print>LocalCreatePrintJob (line 100) handles = > checkArgsForHandleToPrint(0, varargin{:}); 
  >   Error in print (line 38) > [pj, inputargs] = LocalCreatePrintJob(varargin{:}); Error in saveas > (line 181) > print( h, name, ['-d' dev{i}] ) 
  >   Error in GUI>nightly_simulation_Callback (line 909) > saveas(hFig, name, 'pdf'); Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95) > feval(varargin{:}); 
  >   Error in GUI (line 43) > gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in 
matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)GUI('nightly_simulation_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)) > 
Error while evaluating DestroyedObject Callback.

---

Comment: `saveas(hFig,[name '.pdf']);`
may this solve the problem?

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple `Scope` blocks and hence hFig is a vector, which is what `saveas` is complaining about.

You need to have a loop, and save each figure/scope to a different file.  So something like

```
hFig = findall(0,'tag','SIMULINK_SIMSCOPE_FIGURE');
for idx = 1:numel(hFig)
   name = strcat('NCSSimResults','_Scope_',num2str(idx));
   saveas(hFig(idx), name, 'pdf');
end
```

Or perhaps even better would be to get the name of the individual `Scope` blocks and use those as the name of each of the files.

Comment: Actually I want to save these figures in one pdf-file, but I made it with help of mattesyo's suggestion code 'saveas(hFig,[name '.pdf']);' But I will keep your suggested code for that case of saving figures in separate pdf-files in my mind. Thank you very much!